# ComponentQuery for a parent with ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

Is there a way to query "up"? I'm in a Component and want to register listeners to it's parents events with control(). This requires a Query which gets me the parent of my main view.

Comment: every question contains 80% of the answer :)  ... up()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ExtJS4, you can use 'up()' from an Ext Element.

The params are a string of the parent element you wish to find e.g:

```
var parentEl = Ext.get('childID').up('div.parentClass');
```

If you provide some details about the structure of your components/elements I can give a specific example which should fit.

EDIT: To show going 'up' from a component

```
var myComponent = // however you've got it

var theParentEl = myComponent.getEl().up('div.parentClass');
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about the `up()` method, but I need this functionality as a component query selector.

Comment: From a Component you can either use getEl() to get the containing element (then use the up method as described) or you could go down the route of using Component.findParentByType(xtype) which returns an Ext Container.

Comment: so, going up is just possible with methods? Something like "a < b" would be nice haha. thank you anyways :)

Comment: You can use the component query 'query()' with a selector pattern like query(div > li) in a similar way as you would do in jQuery, but the disadvantage of this is that you are then dependent on the selector pattern being in place in multiple locations. If you want maximum re-use, using up() will allow you to find a parent by type wherever it lies. Eg. Using up('window') from a button, will always find it's parent window, even when the button is nested deep within other controls.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `up('PARENTCLASS')` is enough for what you're trying to do. Here is what I do all over the code so elements generates event for the form they are in:

```
items: [
...
   { xtype: 'checkbox', listeners: {
      change: function() { this.up('window').fireEvent('checkboxchanged'); }
   }}
...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to listen to events dispatched by a component's parent from the child component's controller control function specifically.

There is not a query selector like 'parent < component' which you can put in the child controller's control function to listen to parent events.

Normally I would just add the parent view to the child's controller, then you could listen to it's events. But I assume you are not doing this because you are trying to delegate to different controllers or something.

You could fire an event in the child component whenever that parent event occurs. Inside the parent controller you could do it like this:

```
var child = parent.down('child');
child.fireEvent('myOwnEventName', arg1, arg2, arg3, etc);
```

Then you would add a handler for 'myOwnEventName' in the child controller's control function to run the logic you wanted for it.

If the parent doesn't have a controller then you should just add the parent component as a view in the child's controller.

Answer (score 1):

The Sencha help says "Member expressions from candidate Components may be tested. If the expression returns a truthy value, the candidate Component will be included in the query:" in the http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery help.

Took me a while to realize I can do the following in my controller:

```
this.control({
  'window{down("testcomp")}[down]': { beforedestroy: this.doNotCloseIfUnsaved }
});
```

Using the {} operation, we can call any arbitrary code.  **Really bad from an efficiency standpoint**, but it got the job done.  I had to add the [down] because it runs component queries from right to left, so we have to be sure down() exists before we try running it (on every component).  Thus, I was able to attach an event to whatever window holds my component.

Of course, other functions can be used too, like child() instead of down() if you want to ensure it is the immediate child rather than just anywhere below.

Comment: holly molly - i had no idea you can do that. its a bit unreadable if you ask me though.